# Android load winscard.so in Android studio

Tags: android

I can't load .so file in my android application. Tried everything written on internet. 
I am getting this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load winscard from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nnadir.scanertest2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.nnadir.scanertest2-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

Tried this
http://www.drewfrisk.com/including-so-libraries-in-android-studio/

this
http://ivansotof.com/2013/12/including-native-so-libraries-in-android/

this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk

this
http://www.kylethielk.com/blog/include-native-so-library-in-apk-with-android-studio/

and this
[Add pre-built .so files in project using Android Gradle plugin 0.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900814/add-pre-built-so-files-in-project-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-7-3)

Nothing works. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load it like this:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("winscard");
}
```

Don't forget to name your library as `libwinscard.so` and place it under `libs/armeabi` folder.