# How to include .so library to an Android Studio project

Tags: android, sdk, .so

I'm using the Sina SDK in my project.We must include it's .so libs. But I have no idea how to include it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G9ka.png)

I put the .so libs in my jniLibs folder. Then I don't know how to write the gradle code to include them.

```
// Copy *.so files from libs/ folder of your project to native-libs folder
// Adjust if your native libraries are somewhere else..
task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File(project(':yourproject').projectDir, 'libs')) { include '**/*.so' }
    into new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}

// Whenever the code is compiled, also copy the native libs to the build folder
tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

// On "gradle clean" also reverse the copying of the native libraries
clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

// Include the native-libs folder into the final APK
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}
```

I find the code from the network, I don't know how to write it for my project.

Comment: You will have to call System.load()

Comment: Your _jniLibs_ folder has a typo - it is currenty named _jinLibs_

Comment: Note "productFlavors" and children ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900814/add-pre-built-so-files-in-project-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-7-3   review path at which u place the .so