# Android Studio - include and consume .so library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I need to use some native libraries(.so) in my android project. According to some answers here in StackOverflow about this topic, I created a `jniLibs` folder in `app/src/main` and put there my files:

```
armeabi/my_lib.so
armeabi-v7a/my_lib.so
x86/my_lib.so
```

Then, in my activity class I use:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("my_lib");
    }
```

But when I run the app, an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception is generated. If this is important to be noticed, I don't have an Android.mk file, and I haven't changed anything that has to do with this in my `gradle` files. So, the only think I did is to copy-paste my `.so` files in `jniLibs` and to write the code above in my activity. So what might be the cause of this problem? Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package"
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 4

        ndk {
            moduleName "my_so_lib"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["libs"]
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }


    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'armeabi'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you guys for helping but it was a stupid problem. When I imported my `.so` files under `jniLibs`, they were named like `libSONAME.so`. In these lines of code:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libSONAME");
}
```

we should not use `System.loadLibrary("libSONAME");`, but just `System.loadLibrary("SONAME");`.

Then, just build the project and everything was OK.

Thank you all for helping. I hope this will save time to someone else.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution 1**

Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
Folder structure looks like :

```
|--app: 
|--|--src: 
|--|--|--main 
|--|--|--|--jniLibs 
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi 
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
```

Can you please confirm that you have this hierarchy ?

No extra code requires just sync your project and run your application.

Reference 
https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle/tree/master/src/main

**Solution 2**

Add both code snippets in your module gradle.build file as a dependency:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
```

How to create this custom jar:

```
    task nativeLibsToJar(type: Jar, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
        destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
        baseName 'native-libs'
        from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
        into 'lib/'
    }

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

What is your gradle version? If you have a 0.7.3 or a newer version then the next article should help you:
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900814/add-pre-built-so-files-in-project-using-android-gradle-plugin-0-7-3)!

Comment: can you add some explanation.?

Comment: My gradle version is `1.5.0`. I did what the link suggests but I got this error `Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.....`. Should I do anything else?