# add *.so file and wrapper jar in android studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been trying to add webrtc library to my android app which is being developed on Android Studio.

After compiling the webrtc, it gave me two folders. **libs** and **jni**.

**libs** folder contains `libjingle_peerconnection.jar` and `base_java.jar`.

**jni** folder contains the *.so files in subfolders.

I had been using same library files in Eclipse as well. But even after trying lots of questions on SO, I couldn't solve my problem. None of the questions talked about both *.so files and jar wrappers together.

I have tried different combinations of following directory structure:

```
|--app: 
|--|--src: 
|--|--|--main 
|--|--|--|--jni 
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi 
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files 
|--|--|--|--|--x86 
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files 
|--|--|--main
|--|--|--|--|--libs
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--.jar Files
```

I have looked into following SO questions but couldn't get solution to my problem.

[How to include *.so library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)

[Include .so library in apk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683775/include-so-library-in-apk-in-android-studio)

[Android Studio - include and consume .so library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116921/android-studio-include-and-consume-so-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working for some time, I was able to resolve this problem. Here is the new directory structure:

```
|--app:
|--|--libs 
|--|--src: 
|--|--|--main 
|--|--|--|--jniLibs // This should be jniLibs and not just jni, android converts the name to cpp from jni
|--|--|--|--|--armeabi 
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files 
|--|--|--|--|--x86 
|--|--|--|--|--|--.so Files
```